# How link a js file to Android project - Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to link a js file to my android application. If it's possible. To be more specific I am developing an app using HTML(I don’t need help with this part) and I want to get my template working, it has mixed parts of html, css and javascript. This is what I have so far at the head of my sheet. ( I don’t know how to make code appear on here, I do have the < & /> in the original.

`link rel="javascript" href="java2/jquery/mobile-slide-menu.js"`

`script type="text/javascript" src="java2/jquery-mobile-slide-menu.js"`

This is what I am trying to make:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/jquery/1.9.1/5624435/

Is it possible to have html,css and javascript in one page or do I have to link them for them to work.

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either way as you are not using the webview javascript bridge directly it does nto matter which way you choose

Your choice will depend on which way you want to keep track of changes in the javascript and html css combination ..separately through different files or one single html file

Comment: Is it possible to have it in a single HTML file? If so how would that be possible, I have tried many times and it's just not working for me.